# How to implement claim-based multi-tenancy with OpenIddict?

Tags: c#, .net, openiddict

This a peculiar problem, I suppose. I'm writing my own authorization server both as a way to learn, and as a way to POC our potential future SSO solution for all our in-house apps at the company where I work. Using the fantastic OpenIddict.

I'm set on a multi-tenant architecture using a db per tenant and Finbuckle.MultiTenant ; meta-tenant information is registered in a special database called "tenants" (using PostgreSQL). What happens is that before the user is logged in, the tenant is null and the login form contains the field "client id" as well as username & password. When the user submits the form, I have set a delegate strategy to read the tenant information from the form data and I can then login the user against its tenant database. At any point the tenancy works with dependency injection by injecting the tenant’s connection string in the scoped DbContext instance. Thereafter his client id (tenant id) is stored as a claim ; at this point in a cookie.

The step 2 happens where the user is directed towards /authorize to retrieve his code. This works well. But hell breaks loose when going to /token. What happens is two scenarios

1. If UseMultiTenant() is before UseAuthentication(), then it can't retrieve the tenant because the claims aren't set yet
2. If it is the opposite, UseAuthentication() breaks because it can't authorize the incoming request against the tenant's database (it doesn't know who the tenant is)

I don't know how to get out of this deadlock in a clean way and I would very much appreciate any insight.

I tried switching the middlewares around (obviously) ; a possible solution would be to implement a simple middleware that would decode the incoming authorization code and then inject the tenant that way. But it's not very clean. The best solution would probably to make OpenIddict tenant-aware somehow.

Comment: Can you move tenant AuthN logic (I guess it's hashed, salted passwords) to the shared tenants DB? Then use middleware ordering 2. If I understand correctly.

Comment: @TreyMack not really, our clients feel more comfortable with clear data isolation. Even if we’re considering the option, we would still need a way to distinguish who owns each row (in this case user data). We wouldn’t have solved the problem. The problem resides with the fact that the tenancy resolution is claim based. And having the tenant in the route or something is hardly a solution for us